# Contrast too high on PS4

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

On my PS4, Minecraft has an incredibly high contrast, being particularly bad to see at night. The water is extremely bright blue, for example. This version of Minecraft has no options for contrast, only gamma, which doesn't help. This is not a problem on other games on the PS4.
Does anyone know why this happens, or a way to fix it?

Comment: Is it just Minecraft, or everything?

Answer (score 1):

LCE (Legacy Console Edition, your edition) does that. go to options and somewhere in there should be gamma, turn that down. maybe there's a "Video Options" tab, it should be in there.

Sorry if my response wasn't useful, I haven't played LCE in years.

Comment: I was typing in to turn down the gamma when you answered, haha! : )

Comment: Gamma doesn't help- all other games seem fine I don't know what's wrong